# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to clear the text box but i am getting

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration
>   or timeout: 30.14 seconds

Following is the html:

```
<input id="cardZipCode" class="padding-left8" type="text" autocomplete="false" maxlength="5" value="10251" name="cardZipCode"/>
```

for that i am using id attribute.
while i am checking textbox it is enable or not, the output is true but while checking for displayed or not the output is false.
and when trying to clear the text box getting `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException`

Tried with following javascriptexecuter code also

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('cardZipCode').value = ' ';");
```

but getting the same error.

Please help me on this.

Comment: can you please paste your code here.

Comment: Hi karthik I am sending my code in another answer because code cant be send in comment

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.14 seconds

code:

```
       WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-toggle='tab' and @href='#admin_tab']"));
    String tabname = tab.getText();
    tab.click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    if(tabname.equals("Admin"))
        {
        System.out.println("user login as admin successfully!");
        ***WebElement adminTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='admin_admin_nav']/a"));***
        String text = adminTab.getText();
        System.out.println(""+adminTab);
        adminTab.click();

        if(text.equals("Admin"))
        {
            System.out.println("Users navigates to the Admin>Admin tab successfully!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("User is in some other tab.");
        }
        }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("User is not a admin user"); 
    }
```

application html code for this is below:


 [Users](https://192.168.0.197:3007/admin/users)